# Can't search for a certain word in a PDF on OS X

Tags: macos, pdf, osx-lion, search

I'm searching [this PDF](http://core.edu.au/cms/images/downloads/conference/08sort%20coderankacronymERA2010_conference_list.pdf) (84 pages) for the word 'software', which appears regularly – but neither Safari or Preview can find it.

If I search for 'soft' it finds instances like "VISSOFT', which is right next to the word 'Software' that it doesn't find.  I'm interested to know:

Am I going mad? 
Is this a replicable problem? (I'm Running on Lion)
What can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It breaks because the "ft" in "Software" is embedded as [a ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) between the letters, not as the individual letters. This obviously is a sign of high quality typography, but the readers don't support it when searching.

[image]

When you select and copy the word from the PDF, you actually get "So_ware", which you can then paste into the search field to finally get your results.

[image]

Comment: Nice... fooled by that beautiful lettering!

Comment: How did you create the `ft` ligature example?

Comment: Wikipedia did ;) @dan